# Bulge out/ Pop effect in CSS on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to replicate a css effect(probably) created on the website [themekaverse](https://themekaverse.com). So if we go down to '*Join our Discord*' section of this website, we can find this animation, where, there is a mesh like structure in the background and when we hover our mouse over it, the mesh bulges out quite smoothly, as some kind of 3d transformation.

```
You can checkout the animation demo at: https://imgur.com/a/remy2zj
```

Please let me know what is the best way to achieve this?

My current attempt is to create a grid of divs and add transform matrix3d to it. But i am not able to achieve similar results.

[image]

Comment: The mesh is likely Canvas or WebGL, not CSS.

Comment: ^-------- agreed, it is a canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small example I whipped up that gives you a *similar* effect using 2D canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("c");

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function redraw(mouseX, mouseY) {
  const meshResX = 50;
  const meshResY = 20;
  const maxDistance = 100;
  const meshW = canvas.width / meshResX;
  const meshH = canvas.height / meshResY;
  const meshPoints = [];
  for (let y = 0; y < meshResY; y++) {
    const line = [];
    meshPoints.push(line);
    for (let x = 0; x < meshResX; x++) {
      let pointX = x * meshW;
      let pointY = y * meshH;
      // Compute distance and direction of mouse to point
      const dx = mouseX - pointX;
      const dy = mouseY - pointY;
      const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
      const a = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      if (distance < maxDistance) {
        // Compute force
        const force = Math.sin((distance / maxDistance) * Math.PI) * -20;
        // Apply force to point
        pointX += Math.cos(a) * force;
        pointY += Math.sin(a) * force;
      }
      line.push({ x: pointX, y: pointY });
    }
  }
  // Draw the mesh
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let y = 0; y < meshResY - 1; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < meshResX - 1; x++) {
      const p1 = meshPoints[y][x];
      const p2 = meshPoints[y][x + 1];
      const p3 = meshPoints[y + 1][x + 1];
      const p4 = meshPoints[y + 1][x];
      ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
      ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y);
      ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(p4.x, p4.y);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = e.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = e.clientY - rect.top;
  redraw(x, y);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Mouse over below:<br>
<canvas width="1024" height="400" id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: similar but that one is smooth animation.

Comment: @Shawn What do you mean? I did change the force computation to be more clamped now.

Comment: your one is little bit faster but that one is smoother and that one color is lighter than yours btw nice try hope it will be okay

Comment: Yeah, mine doesn't have the same bouncy interpolation animation (mine only updates when you move the mouse) and changing the color is trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer! How did you identify it? It would be really helpful if you could share similar resources and topics to learn and understand and in general identify such animations. Thanks !

Comment: Knowing it was canvas was an educated guess, and from there it was just... general knowledge, I suppose!